# how to register our windows mobile for test the app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I try to test my windows phone app on my mobile. for that i created a developer account as company. i paid the amount. when i try to register my mobile it tells that "Please check that the Zune software is running and that Zune's sync partnership with your phone has been established". when i check my developer account dashboard it tells that

"Validating your account. Learn more.
You haven’t completed your tax profile. If you’re interested in publishing paid apps, update your tax info here. Learn more.
We don't have a payment account for you. To add this info, go here. Learn more."

Please guide me....

I try to test my app in nokia lumia 710

We dont want paid apps account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register Company account there is an additional validation. Microsoft contacts you'r company and talks about something. I don;t know really about what, but in my company we also waited about 1-2 months.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please check that the Zune software is running and that Zune's sync partnership with your phone has been established

Ans : For testing your app in lumia 710, first you need to install [Zune software](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp7/zune-software). Then you have unlock your phone for testing the app.

2) Validating your account. Learn more. You haven’t completed your tax profile. If you’re interested in publishing paid apps, update your tax info here. Learn more. We don't have a payment account for you.

Ans : For complete details please have [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/bg124529.aspx)

Comment: * I dont want and paid app account so i think tax profile is not necessary